# selected button value, when assigned to a variable returns undefined

Tags: jquery

This returns the selected value and works fine:

```
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '#square', function () {
            confirm($('input[type="radio"][name="plot"]:checked').val());
        });
    });
```

This returns undefined:

```
     $('document').ready(function () {
         var $userInput;
         $userInput = $('input[type="radio"][name="plot"]:checked').val();
         $(document).on('click', '#square', function () {
             confirm($userInput);
         });
     });
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first scenario you grab the value on click, in the second you get the value on page load.

Solution: Grab the value in the event handler as the first example shows.